# Generate a random number between a to b

Tags: excel, vba, button, random

I have knowledge of the RANDBETWEEN() function inside the cells of Excel. This only returns one (1) value. I would like to assign this to a button to return a different value every time the button is hit.

I can create the button, I have the cell. How can I link the two?

Long story short, every time a button is clicked a cell (lets say cell a1) gets a different value between values a to b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're still using the RANDBETWEEN function and you just want it to generate a new value on command, just press F9 to force Excel to recalculate all formulas. RANDBETWEEN will then generate a new random number. (If it doesn't change value, it's just because it generated the same random number by chance. Keep pressing F9 to get new random numbers.)

Note that changing any formula on the spreadsheet will also cause the RANDBETWEEN function to generate a new value.

If you want a new random number to be generated ONLY when you command it to, then you do need to create a macro, which can be easily called through a button. I'm assuming you're not familiar with macros at all, so the following is a simple solution.

The following website explains how to create a simple button that will run a macro. (Note that this specific method only works with the ActiveX button, not the Forms button.)

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_excel_macros.htm

You will just need to replace the code in their example (MsgBox "Hi") with the following code:

```
Range("A1") = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(a,b)
```

Replace a and b with the numbers you want to get a random number between. You can do this a few ways:

If you always want it between the same two numbers (e.g. 1 and 10), you can hard-code them into the macro:

```
Range("A1") = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1,10)
```

If you want it between two numbers recorded on the same spreadsheet (e.g. in cells B1 and B2), you can refer to the cells:

```
Range("A1") = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(Range("B1"),Range("B2"))
```

Or you can ask for the numbers in popups:

```
a = InputBox("Enter a")
b = InputBox("Enter b")
Range("A1") = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(a, b)
```

Note that the website misses a couple of important steps you must perform before the button will be able to used:

1. Close the VBA window (not actually necessary, but there's no need to leave it open)
2. Exit Design Mode. On the Developer tab in Excel, the Design Mode button should still be highlighted. Click it to un-highlight it. You can now click your button.

Note that if you want to change the code for the button again, you need to click Design Mode again to highlight it again, then you can double click the button to view the code again.

Comment: thanks for the reply. now, say I want to create several cells to randomly generate between different values (such as 1-100, 1-20, 1-1000 etc.) will this update all functions? or just one cell? personally id rather it just update one cell. perhaps creating several buttons to do all the different cells I need to generate, is that possible?

Comment: You can either create separate buttons, each with a separate macro to update a different cell; or separate buttons to update the same cell with different values ranges; or you can update the macro for the one button to update multiple cells, just by adding more lines of code with the different locations and values you want.

Comment: this worked, I have what I need to continue crafting the excel file for my needs thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Try below

```
Private Sub CreateRandom()

  'random number between 11 and 100
  Debug.Print NewRandom(11, 100)

End Sub

Private Function NewRandom(ByVal FromLimit As Integer, ByVal ToLimit As Integer) As Integer

    Randomize
    randomNumber = Int((ToLimit - FromLimit) * Rnd) + FromLimit
    NewRandom = randomNumber

End Function

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

  'random number between 30 and 100
  Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = NewRandom(30, 100)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

MI Consol:

```
Sheets:
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call p
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Call save
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Call EMail
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
Call iSMS
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
Call continue
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()
Call Continue1
End Sub
```